# How can I force Haxe to compile all source classes?

Tags: haxe

I'm finding when building Haxe projects that only code referenced from Main or by a class that is indirectly/directly referenced in Main is compiled.  How can I force Haxe to compile all source .HX files into the target language? I've tried using the DCE flags (no, std, and full), but none of them seem to make a difference. Working on 3.1.3 for a Haxe version.

**Update**: So using the macro described in the answer below, my solution was to create a root level package for the library I am building and then include that package name in a macro compiler option to include that and all sub-packages, thus ensuring that Haxe compiles all classes, regardless of being referenced directly or indirectly through main.

An example of this would be, if your root level package name was *rootPackage*, add an additional compiler option like so:

```
--macro include('rootPackage', true)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're using haxe 3.1.3 instead of 3.03, which we don't have such release.

Add `--macro include(...)` in your hxml.

Doc:
http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Compiler.html#include

Remember to use single quotes (`'string'`) instead of double quotes (`"string"`) for the params.

Comment: Thanks for responding, you're right, it is 3.1.3. That's what I get for posting at nearly 2 in the morning :) Looking at the api link you posted, seems like it takes either a single string or array of strings of package names. Would using a single root package name with the recursive flag set to true achieve my goal of including all subpackages and their hx source file s? I'll test that theory later this morning and reply back.